# EXCEL - Pivot chart times series when pivot chart has no row field

Tags: excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I have a pivot chart with dates as columns and the max time for max batch job completion time as values. I need to plot a simple line chart with the dates on the x-axis and times on the y-axis. Excel, however, sees the dates as categorical instead of continuous. How can I plot the dates as continuous so I can get a line chart?

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. Not sure this is possible. Maybe create a hidden pivot with the dates as the row field and base your chart off that?

Comment: How about an example of your data (preferably as text) and a picture of what you hope to produce?

Comment: Pivot charts don't do time axes. You need to create a regular chart.